# Send post request in angular 6 without wait to response

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, http-post, dom-events

I want to send a http post request from an angular 6 app when I close my app.
My problem is when I close the app, the http request gets aborted.
How can I send a http post request without getting it aborted this way? Also I don’t care about the result, I only want the request to be completed in the server.

Answer (score 2):

But is doesn't work because the page is closing and it doesn't get to the subscribe and in the network it said that the request was canceled

Comment: Exacty, what he is looking for is beacon.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Answer (score 1):

I would subscribe, because if not it won't fire. Then do nothing with the response.

```
this.http.post( url, body, headers ).subscribe(
   data => {
            // don't do nothing
           }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Then (assuming you're using the HttpClient), you will just call the method without the subscription logic like that:

```
this.http.post(URL,BODY).subscribe();
```